# Why does a closured function not protect the values of an object but a naked function will?

Tags: javascript, closures, lodash

Why does a closured function not protect the values of an object but a naked function will?
[I have the below code on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u8cuk/7/).

I'm using Lo-Dash `_.assign` function with a default `Object`. Like so:

```
var cnst = _.constant({test: 'It Works!'})
var newCnst = _.assign(cnst(), {test: "It doesn't work!"})
console.log(cnst())
console.log(newCnst)
```

Which results in:

```
{test: "It doesn't work!"}
{test: "It doesn't work!"}
```

So I just do a naked constant function like so:

```
var test = function(){return {test: 'It Works!'}}
var newTest = _.assign(test(), {test: "It doesn't work!"})
console.log(test())
console.log(newTest)
```

Which results in:

```
{test: 'It Works!'}
{test: "It doesn't work!"}
```

Just like it should. Why is the closured constant value not protected? Even when I do it myself:

```
var constant = function(value){return function(){return value}}
var t = constant({test: 'Closured Works!'})
var t2 = _.assign(t(), {test: "No closured doesn't work!"})
console.log(t())
console.log(t2)
```

Which results in:

```
{test: "No closured doesn't work!"}
{test: "No closured doesn't work!"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that in both the Lo-Dash example and in custom `constant` implementation, the function created always returns a reference to the *same* instance. That is to say, in both these snippets only one object is ever created:

```
var cnst = _.constant({test: 'It Works!'})

var constant = function(value){return function(){return value}}
var t = constant({test: 'Closured Works!'})
```

This can be confirmed by checking:

```
console.log(newCnst === cnst()) // true
console.log(t2 === t())         // true
```

However, in this example:

```
var test = function(){return {test: 'It Works!'}}
```

A new object is created every time the function is called. So when you call:

```
var newTest = _.assign(test() /* new object created here */, {test: "It doesn't work!"})
console.log(test() /* new object created here */)
console.log(newTest)
```

This can be confirmed by checking:

```
console.log(newTest === test()) // false
```